# How to obtain <servlet><init-param> inside a servlet? getServletContext().getInitParameter() does not seem to find them

Tags: servlets

In web.xml I have two initial parameters name Premier and Regular. To show you the code this is it.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StockServelt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.StockServelt</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Premier</param-name>
        <param-value>/Premier</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Regular</param-name>
        <param-value>/Regular</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I have Create two constants (named PREMIER AND REGULAR) and I want to retrieve the configuration intial parameters name "Regular" and "Premier".

This is my code for that. I am not sure I am doing this part right or not

```
final String PREMIER = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Premier");
final String REGULAR = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Regular");
```

Here I print both to the console make sure that I retrieved correctly. But I am getting a null for both

```
System.out.println("This is the value for Premier: " + PREMIER + " "
            + "and this is the value for Regular: " + REGULAR);
```

Can someone please help me out her what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing all this in a JSF request (which I don't understand if you are) you can get the init-parameters with

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>Premier</param-name>
    <param-value>/Premier</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(note: not inside the servlet-tag)

and

```
final String PREMIER = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameter("Premier");
```

This is just a comment as I don't know if it solves anything and/or there are other problems.

Comment: Jaqen, OP is using a plain vanilla servlet, not a JSF backing bean. The `FacesContext` is not available in a custom servlet at all.

Comment: Alright thanks @BalusC